# ¿Como cerrar un Modal de Materialize desde JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, modal, materialize

Les agradesco de antemano
Estoy haciendo un trabajo, estoy queriendo cerrar un Modal de Materialize al oprimir un boton que valide cierta acción. Según la documentación de Materialize solo debo conseguir la instancia de un elemento
**Ejemplo de Materialize**
var instance = M.Modal.getInstance(elem);

Ahora quiero saber como hacerlo ya que no me lo cierra.
/*Mi codigo en Js el Modal se llama y posee un id de modalPIN*/

```
var comprobarPIN = document.getElementById('recuperarPIN');
comprobarPIN.addEventListener('click', function () {
    let pin = 123;
    let pinintro = document.getElementById('recuperarPIN');
    let elem = document.getElementById('modalPIN')
    let modal = M.Modal.getInstance(elem);
    alert("no funciono");
    modal.close();
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Lo logre encontrar por si alguien esta igual de perdido que yo: dentro del querySelector esta el nombre de su Modal

```
let modal = M.Modal.getInstance(document.querySelector('#modalPIN'));
modal.close();
```